# How do you properly deserialize a class that has an IReadOnlyCollection<T> using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, system.text.json, readonly-collection

I have the following class:

```
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    [JsonConstructor()]
    public SomeClass(IEnumerable<string> myItems)
    {
        InternalMyItems = new Collection<string>(myItems.ToArray());
        MyItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(InternalMyItems);
    }
    
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> MyItems { get; }
    private Collection<string> InternalMyItems { get; }
}
```

Serialization seems to work fine:

```
{
  "MyItems": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ]
}
```

Deserialization doesn't seem to work. Ideally, I'd like to stick to using `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `Collection<T>` and not have to change to some other types. This sample code throws an exception when attempting to deserialize:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    WriteIndented = true
};

var items = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var instance = new SomeClass(items);

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(instance, options);

var copy = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeClass>(json, options);
```

> InvalidOperationException: Each parameter in the deserialization
> constructor on type 'UserQuery+SomeClass' must bind to an object
> property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match
> with a property or field on the object. Fields are only considered
> when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields' is enabled. The match can
> be case-insensitive.

---

Here is a .NET Fiddle example of the code running and giving an error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vorOLX

Comment: Does the receive json look like the serialized json?

Comment: @jdweng: I don't know what the 'receive json' you speak of is? I capture the json from serialization and use the same json (output shown above) to try to deserialize.

Comment: @PoulBak: Above which property (or both)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type and name of constructor parameters must match the properties in the class. System.Text.Json also knows how to construct a `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` directly, so just use that type. For example, you could simply do this:

```
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public SomeClass(IReadOnlyCollection<string> myItems)
                   // ^^^^ matching type         
    {
        MyItems = myItems;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> MyItems { get; }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, but it looks like I'll have to create another constructor then, because I use this constructor with the `IEnumerable<T>` all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?pivots=dotnet-7-0):

> The parameter names of a parameterized constructor must match the property names **and types**.

You can try using `IReadOnlyCollection` and match the types:

```cs
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    [JsonConstructor()]
    public SomeClass(IReadOnlyCollection<string> myItems)
    {
        InternalMyItems = new Collection<string>(myItems.ToArray());
        this.MyItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(InternalMyItems);
    }


    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> MyItems { get; }
    private Collection<string> InternalMyItems { get; }
}
```

If needed you can keep the original ctor:

```cs
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConstructor()]
    public SomeClass(IReadOnlyCollection<string> myItems)
    {
        InternalMyItems = new Collection<string>(myItems.ToArray());
        this.MyItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(InternalMyItems);
    }

    public SomeClass(IEnumerable<string> myItems)
    {
        InternalMyItems = new Collection<string>(myItems.ToArray());
        MyItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(InternalMyItems);
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> MyItems { get; }
    private Collection<string> InternalMyItems { get; }
}
```